# Customize jquery autocomplete result

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I'm using the jQuery autocomplete with a remote data source

```
    $( "input#searchbar" ).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({type: "post",
            mode: "abort",
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'index.php/ajax/autosuggest',
            data: { term: $("#searchbar").val()},
            success: function(data) {

                response(data);
            }
        });
    },
    select: function(e, ui) {
        //Refresh pros
        if (map){
            mouseUpOnTheMap();
        }
    }
});
```

It works really well. When i type "a" there is a list of activity (fetched from a database) starting with that are listed. What i would like to do it's add a custom parametre (the ID of the activity) in the result.

Because when a user select an activity later I will have to "re-do" a sql search to get the ID of the activity...

So is there a way to include the activity id in the returned JSON from the autocomplete ?

THanks

Comment: Where you will save that id ? clientside or DB

Answer (score 3):

If your index.php/ajax/autosuggest page returns an array of JSON objects with two keys of "label" and "value" (instead of an array of strings), the the jQuery UI Autocomplete plugin with use the "label" key to display in the autocomplete list, but actually give you the JSON object that was selected in the select event. Then you can reference the value of the object.

```
$( "input#searchbar" ).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({type: "post",
            mode: "abort",
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'index.php/ajax/autosuggest',
            data: { term: $("#searchbar").val()},
            success: function(data) {
                //data assumes [{label: "result 1", value: 1}, {label: "result 2", value: 2}];
                response(data);
            }
        });
    },
    select: function(e, ui) {
        var selectedItem = ui.item;
        var id = selectedItem.value;
        var label = selectedItem.label;

        //Refresh pros
        if (map){
            mouseUpOnTheMap();
        }
    }
});
```

I haven't tested thist, just found it here: http://www.petefreitag.com/item/756.cfm

Comment: Actually, after re-reading that page there may be a little more work involved. My bad for jumping the gun on this one.... it's early.

Answer (score 1):

The way Wesley described is what we're currently using as well.

By returning both `label` and `id` in our JSON objects we are able to grab that id handle it in the way we want (in our case, storing it in a hidden input), while the label is being used to show our users which record is selected.

Basic example: http://jsfiddle.net/NLK5p/4/

Answer (score 0):

Which datasource are you using ? I strongly suggest **freebase** it's a free database within more than 12 millions of voices and it provides a web services for the autosuggestion (included js functions) in the most miscellanous fields (jobs, sports, actors, movies or whatever you wish)... not everybody knows about it but google bought the project last year (it still available and free) so it should be a promising web service for datasources.